# Script not connected to the terminal

Tags: linux

I've run a python scriptfile called `prime.py` that lists all the prime numbers less than 2000 in the terminal. If I use `nohup` and run it, then even if I close the terminal, the process will not stop and the script will not list any prime numbers in the terminal. The command I've entered for this is

```
nohup python -u prime.py
```

If I want to save the output of this script onto a file named `log.dat` using redirect `>`, what command should I enter?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You may find that the obvious answer works.

Comment: I've tried this: `cat python -u prime > ../Desktop/prime.py`

Comment: Do you want to log the output of your python script or of `cat`? Then where does that cat come from?

Comment: And, do you really want to be writing script output to a file whose name ends with `.py`?  That could cause confusion — you might subsequently find yourself trying to execute the script *output* as if it were a script.  Also, this risks overwriting an existing script. (And how do you expect the output to go to a file called `log.dat` if you don’t mention `log.dat` in your command?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
nohup python -u prime.py > log.dat
```

It works for me...

Comment: I don't know why I excluded nohup everytime. Thanks man!